# EXPLAIN SELECT in rails 3.2.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My rails app is set up using a mysql database.

When I do a simple find eg:

```
Pin.find(:all).size
```

will result in the following

```
Pin Load (130.1ms)  SELECT `pins`.* FROM `pins` 
  EXPLAIN (0.6ms)  EXPLAIN SELECT `pins`.* FROM `pins` 
EXPLAIN for: SELECT `pins`.* FROM `pins` 
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | pins  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 33385 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

 => 33385
```

How do I turn off the EXPLAIN SELECT  so that:

```
 Pin.find(:all).size
```

will return

```
Pin Load (1719.6ms)  SELECT `pins`.* FROM `pins` 
 => 43774
```

Comment: I figured out that if I run this : 1.9.3-p125 :019 > ActiveRecord::Base.silence_auto_explain { Pin.find(:all).size }
  Pin Load (131.2ms)  SELECT `pins`.* FROM `pins` 
 => 33385  it disables automatic explain, however how I can disable it permanently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In environments/development set

```
config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = nil
```

and this will turn auto explain off.